# CentOS: Mount without sudo

Tags: centos, mount, sudo

Is there a way to `mount` within CentOS 6.3 e.g. `mount /mnt/a /mnt/b` or `mount /mnt/b` (for `/mnt/b` in `/etc/fstab`), without the requirement of using the `sudo` command?

Comment: What are you mounting?  Local block storage?  Network shared?

Comment: Various network and local shares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can be precise about the device to mount, and the mount point, then you can delegate that power via the `user` option in `/etc/fstab`, eg:

```
/dev/sdd1       /mnt            vfat    user    0 0
```

which will allow any user to do `mount /mnt`.

Comment: @DotGeorge, for the `man` page entry, `man 8 mount` and go down to the section on 'non-superuser mounts'.  There are also options for `owner` and `group` if you want only a subset of users being able to mount the specified filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for that, guys. I'm not sure why this didn't occur to me as I'm authenticating with a few of my shares using a credentials file. Cheers.

Comment: Don't forget you can use LABEL or UUID to be less precise than the block device mapping.

Comment: @AaronCopley I've not used the UUID before. What will that give me - some level of abstraction?

Comment: @DotGeorge Correct, every device has a UUID. It's actually more precise than device mapping since this can change on reboot. (I misspoke a bit before.) Run the command `blkid` to enumerate them on your host. There is likely already an example in /etc/fstab using it. (/boot, usually.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add users to the fuse group to allow them to mount in userspace with `fusermount`.